# Incorrect page Render

Tags: c#, asp.net

I trying create a class derivated from System.Web.UI.Page and in override Render i set this code:

```
writer.WriteLine("<![CDATA[");
base.Render(writer);
writer.WriteLine("\r\n]]>");
```

My problem is when i try see code generated

```
<![CDATA[
><form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1"> 
...
</form> 
]]>
```

first > after CDATA is wrong i don't want it generated. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Stupid question but are you sure that the ">" isn't in front of the <form /> on your ASPX page?

Comment: No. My aspx file is clear 0 lines of html or script

Comment: If it is clear where is the form tag coming from?

Comment: Form tag is created dynamically by as.net when you insert an asp.net button control for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the renderer tries to validate the HTML or something similar. Try perhaps render this into a stream, and then Insert and Append the CDATA stuff to it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try rendering an empty DIV tag before calling base.Render?
I suspect that there might be a control or page adapter involved in this, and seeing what happens to the '>' as a result would help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
 HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

 base.Render(hw);

 string a = sb.ToString();
```

its all ok but next when i introduce

```
writer.WriteLine("<![CDATA[");
writer.write (a);
writer.WriteLine("\r\n]]>");
```

the problem persist. I suspect from writer variable (HtmlTextWriter), exist a way for not validate html during render process?